# Skip jump link in browser's history using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, browser-history, html5-history

I use Angular 2 (v2.4.4) and by using `routerLink` I navigate between the components.

This works fine, but if I load the very save component with the very same snapshot parameter (`active.snapshot.params`) the page won't get loaded again. So, for example if I am on `/page/56` and I click on a link here which points to `/page/56`, the very same link (from a menu or something), the component won't reload. (And things might change in the database since the last load, so the page needs to be reloaded.)

I bypassed it by pointing to `/jump/page/56` and the *Page 404* controller redirects to `/page/56`.

This also works fine, but if I navigate back in the browser from `/page/56`, it will get to `/jump/page/56` which directs to `/page/56` by the *Page 404* controller. So basically I cannot navigate back.

As much as I know, I cannot delete browser history by the HTML5 history API, but how could I go back to the page, which was right before `/page/56`, just by simply clicking on the back button of the browser?

The solution might be a simple JavaScript trick independent from Angular 2, as it does not actually load a new page just loads a different component and changes the URL. (Also because of this I should not use `location.reload()` because it will reload Angular 2 and all the depending JS, etc.)

Thank you for your solutions in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use skipLocationChange Like :

`this.router.navigate(['/jump/page/12'],{skipLocationChange:true});`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way is to create your own dicrective inherited from `[routerLink]` to control click handler or just add click handler to current element with managing refresh by yourself.

```
 <a (click)="navigate(['/jump/page/56'])">Navigate</a>
```

where

```
navigate(route) {
  this.router.navigate(route, {replaceUrl: true});
}
```

Comment: Actually, the way I want to "refresh" the page, if I am already on it, that I don't call `location.reload()` (because it reloads the whole system, which takes measurably lot time), but I navigate to a different NG2 component, and back again. But this way I get extra records in the browser's history. And when I navigate back, I get jumped forward again...

Comment: `navigate` method is flexible enough to get different behaviors using different parameters. You can use as refresh page (without full reloading) without adding point to your history setting `replaceUrl` option. Check this link. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html

Comment: So your implementation will looks like `this.router.navigate(route, {replaceUrl: true});`. All you need is to check if url you are navigating to is the current url by comparing `this.router.url` property